# How do I install mmd tools on Blender

Tags: add-on, file-format

I am using version 2.82.7 and am trying to install mmd tools on Blender. It doesn't appear in the addon menu even though I have it in the program files. I used to have an issue where a copy of mmd tools appears in the appdata before I reinstalled Blender trying to fix the issue.[image]

Comment: Hi. Maybe you could provide us with a link to where you downloaded that add-on? You see, not everyone here knows every add-on that ever existed. You can use the [edit link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/172535/edit) at the bottom of your question to add the missing info. Also, please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) to learn how you could help us to give good answers.

Comment: Hello :). Use the [newest build](https://github.com/powroupi/blender_mmd_tools/tree/dev_test#download). And make sure it's the *second* mmd_tools folder. The one *inside*, containing bunch of files with *.py* suffix :)

Comment: I replaced my version of mmd tools with the one you sent me and it worked this time. Thanks